# PHP Form not showing up in recipient's mailbox

Tags: php, email, scripting, forms

My form does not go to recipient when submitted! I changed the file mail.tpl.txt to direct to my own email address as a test and I got the email just fine.

Client has checked junk mail folder as well and he is just not getting information.

Below is the form code, followed by the code from mail.tpl.txt and then the form's index.php code.

Everything looks okay to me, so I am asking if someone has any idea why he wouldn't be getting the form. He uses qwest for email if that helps any.

Here's the form code:

```
<form id="contactForm" name="form" action="form/index.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <legend><font color="#000000"><strong>Please fill out the form below if you have any questions.</strong></font></legend>
    <div>
    <label for="name">Name:* </label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="name" class="txt" id="name" />
  </div>
    <div>
    <label for="label">Phone: </label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="phone" class="txt" id="label" />
  </div>
    <div>
    <label for="email">Email:* </label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="email" class="txt" id="email" />
  </div>
    <div>
    <label for="message">Message: </label>
    <textarea rows="6" name="message" id="message" cols="40" class="txt"></textarea>
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="thanks" value="../thanks.php" />
  <input type="hidden" name="email_fields" value="email" />
  <input type="hidden" name="required_fields" value="name, email" />
  <input type="hidden" name="html_template" value="form.tpl.html" />
  <input type="hidden" name="mail_template" value="mail.tpl.txt" />
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message" name="Submit" id="Submit" />
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now the mail.tpl.text code: (I have taken out my client's full address and domain name for the post.)

```
    To: "xxxxxxx Custom Homes" <xxxxxxx@q.com>
    From: "{name}" {phone} <{email}> <{message}>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/plain; charset={txt_charset}
    Subject: Online Contact Request from Freese Custom Homes

    Contact Information:
    {name} {phone}
    Email Address: {email}

    Contact Message:
    {message}

Lastly, here's the form's index.php code: (Again, I have taken out my client's domain name for the post)

<?php

          $script_root           = './';

          $referring_server      = ''; // Example: $referring_server = 'xxxxxxx.com, www.xxxxxxx.com';

          $language              = 'en';      // (see folder 'languages')

          $ip_banlist            = '';

          $ip_address_count      = '0';
          $ip_address_duration   = '48';

          $show_limit_errors     = 'yes';    // (yes, no)

          $log_messages          = 'no';     // (yes, no) -- make folder "temp" writable with: chmod 777 temp

          $text_wrap             = '72';

          $show_error_messages   = 'yes';

          $attachment            = 'no';    // (yes, no) -- make folder "temp" writable with: chmod 777 temp
          $attachment_files      = 'jpg, gif,png, zip, txt, pdf, doc, ppt, tif, bmp, mdb, xls, txt';
          $attachment_size       =  9000000;

          $captcha               = 'no';   // (yes, no) -- make folder "temp" writable with: chmod 777 temp

          $path['logfile']       = $script_root . 'logfile/logfile.txt';
          $path['templates']     = $script_root . 'templates/';

          $file['default_html']  = 'form.tpl.html';
          $file['default_mail']  = 'mail.tpl.txt';

  /*****************************************************
  ** Add further words, text, variables and stuff
  ** that you want to appear in the templates here.
  ** The values are displayed in the HTML output and
  ** the e-mail.
  *****************************************************/
          $add_text = array(
                              'txt_additional' => 'Additional', //  {txt_additional}
                              'txt_more'       => 'More'        //  {txt_more}

                            );

  /*****************************************************
  ** Do not edit below this line - Ende der Einstellungen
  *****************************************************/

  /*****************************************************
  ** Send safety signal to included files
  *****************************************************/
          define('IN_SCRIPT', 'true');

  /*****************************************************
  ** Load formmail script code
  *****************************************************/
          include($script_root . 'inc/formmail.inc.php');

          echo $f6l_output;

?>
```

Comment: 'yes' and 'no' instead of TRUE or FALSE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sending a plain text email right now - you should correct the header content type of that email.

Just set it to text/html. There might be more information here:

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387.txt
- http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822

Or google for it, there are plenty of sources out there!

Answer (score 1):

To add the appropiate headers, see:
http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
example 4.
This btw is just Sebastian's aswer with a link.

Answer (score 1):

The From header line is not correct. There is text outside of the quotes:

```
From: "{name}" {phone} <{email}> <{message}>
```

And what's the <{message}> doing there. The only correct format would be:

```
From: "{name} {phone}" <{email}>
```

You can't use the message placeholder there because it contains new lines and that will break the mail header.